# Error - "The merchant does not accept payments of this type" in Paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, merchant-account

I have an US Paypal account. I have integrated Paypal iOS SDK. Payment through Card is working fine in Sandbox mode but when I go live with live client ID it is showing error i.e. "The merchant does not accept payments of this type".

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Live account doesn't have necessary toggles for receiving direct card payment. Please contact PayPal Customer Service team for checking the toggles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the card you are using is a prepaid card/gift card